# Screen brightness decreases when I middle-click

Tags: macos, mouse, display

I have a logitech wireless mouse hooked up to a macbook pro running 10.7. Whenever I middle-click the mouse button, the laptop's display brightness decreases. It behaves just as if I had pressed the F1 key. The middle-click still works in applications (e.g. Firefox opens a new tab), it just has this annoying side-effect. How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Does it dim temporarily or only while you have the button down?  Does the onscreen display brightness indicator display when this happens?

Comment: The indicator appears and the brightness stays decreased until I press F2. If I middle-click enough the display goes completely dark.

Comment: Okay.  It sounds like you're middle click has been mapped to that key somehow.  Did you install logitech's software for controlling what those buttons do?

Comment: No, I didn't realize there was such software. I'll check it out.

Comment: Have you checked the Mouse settings in System Preferences too?

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is change the key mappings on your mouse. What this does is tells your computer what to do when you press key X.

For Mac…

> [MapKeyboard](http://m.download.cnet.com/MapKeyboard/3000-2094_4-10623201.html) is a free program to remap your keyboard. Using MapKeyboard, you can alter any key on your keyboard to function as a different one or altogether disable it as well. This is an essential tool for laptop users and other people with keyboards whose keys differ from the standard 101 keyboard layout.

For Windows…

> [SetPoint Software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/articles/11650)
>
> Logitech SetPoint™ software lets you customize your mouse buttons, keyboard F-keys, and hot keys. Use SetPoint to control tracking speeds and configure other device-specific settings. It can also notify you of our device’s battery status, and whether Caps Lock and Num Lock are on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link is the essential part of the question. It leads to the official download page for the software that can help with the problem...

Comment: This appears to be a Windows only software solution.

Comment: Added a Mac solution